# Windows XP - randomly My Computer will not respond and clock display does not update

Tags: windows-xp, freeze

On Windows XP - randomly My Computer will not respond and the clock display stops.  The My Computer window opens,  icons usually display,  but then they will not respond to clicks. I have to CTRL+ALT+DEL to terminate it.

This also may happen with other "Windows" that sit on the desktop as holders for icons.

This occurs randomly and will usually clear itself up, but that may be an hour or so later.

Comment: The behavior you describe is the association sign of a bad system hdd

Comment: Interesting thought, but its been happening on and off for almost a year. One drive is a year old,the other 1.5, the MB and CPU are 4 years old. How would I know for sure, I need to keep this machine running for a least 3 months, until I finish moving to Windows 7 on a new computer.

Comment: You can replace the hdd and hardware failures can take awhile my failed hdd was "working" for 3 months

Comment: Also, to clarify, when My Computer (or another window) hangs, I can keep using other applications on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is similar to what is happening to me.

In my case, it is the computer swapping memory in and out, so it locks for 20 or so seconds when I have a lot of windows open (including Chrome, about 25).

The active window keeps working.